# Deploying ADF faces in tomcat 6

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, oracle-adf

Finally I have managed to bring up my adf web application in tomcat server. But now I'm stuck with one issue, when I try to access my page it gives me the following error,

```
22/01/2012 2:47:39 AM oracle.jsp.logger.JspMessages infoCannotDispatchJspPage
INFO: Unable to dispatch JSP Page : Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/classloader/PolicyClassLoader
```

Thinking that its again an error because of jar, I searched to download the jar, I have found the jar name but I cannot find the jar anywhere to download , the name I have found is "pcl.jar"

But I cannot find what is the real problem, I have did all the things I could to get the fullest log but this is what I can find.

```
WARNING: Errors processing schema:jar:file:/C:/tomcat635/lib/adfm.jar!/oracle/adfdt/model/schema/main.xsd
oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDException
        at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDBuilder.buildSchema(XSDBuilder.java:748)
        at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDBuilder.build(XSDBuilder.java:407)
        at oracle.bali.xml.grammar.schema.OracleSchemaFactory.buildSchemas(OracleSchemaFactory.java:213)
        at oracle.bali.xml.grammar.schema.OracleSchemaFactory.buildSchemas(OracleSchemaFactory.java:159)
        at oracle.bali.xml.grammar.schema.SchemaGrammarProvider.addSchema(SchemaGrammarProvider.java:64)
        at oracle.mds.internal.type.InternalTypeManager.addSchema(InternalTypeManager.java:548)
        at oracle.mds.internal.type.InternalTypeManager.addSchemasFromTypeConfig(InternalTypeManager.java:480)
        at oracle.mds.internal.type.InternalTypeManager.<init>(InternalTypeManager.java:103)
        at oracle.mds.type.TypeManager.create(TypeManager.java:102)
        at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.<init>(MDSInstance.java:1795)
        at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.<init>(MDSInstance.java:1738)
        at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.findAndStoreMDSInstance(MDSInstance.java:2035)
        at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.getOrCreateInstance(MDSInstance.java:529)
        at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.getOrCreateInstance(MDSInstance.java:492)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFMDSConfig.getDefaultMDSInstance(ADFMDSConfig.java:450)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.FallbackConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(FallbackConfigImpl.java:64)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.FallbackConfigImpl.getDefaultMDSInstance(FallbackConfigImpl.java:95)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFConfigImpl.java:602)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFConfigImpl.java:582)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFContextMDSConfigHelperImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFContextMDSConfigHelperImpl.java:274)
        at oracle.adf.share.ADFContext.getMDSInstanceAsObject(ADFContext.java:1757)
        at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext.initialize(ServletADFContext.java:494)
        at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext.initThreadContext(ServletADFContext.java:401)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.HttpBindingRequestHandler.initADFContext(HttpBindingRequestHandler.java:55)
        at oracle.adf.model.BindingRequestHandler.beginRequest(BindingRequestHandler.java:109)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:122)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
22/01/2012 2:59:05 AM oracle.bali.xml.grammar.schema.OracleSchemaFactory buildSchemas
WARNING: Errors processing schema:jar:file:/C:/tomcat635/lib/adfm.jar!/oracle/adfdt/model/schema/ui/jcuimodel.xsd
oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDException
        at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDBuilder.buildSchema(XSDBuilder.java:748)
        at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDBuilder.build(XSDBuilder.java:407)
        at oracle.bali.xml.grammar.schema.OracleSchemaFactory.buildSchemas(OracleSchemaFactory.java:213)
        at oracle.bali.xml.grammar.schema.OracleSchemaFactory.buildSchemas(OracleSchemaFactory.java:159)
        at oracle.bali.xml.grammar.schema.SchemaGrammarProvider.addSchema(SchemaGrammarProvider.java:64)
        at oracle.mds.internal.type.InternalTypeManager.addSchema(InternalTypeManager.java:548)
        at oracle.mds.internal.type.InternalTypeManager.addSchemasFromTypeConfig(InternalTypeManager.java:480)
        at oracle.mds.internal.type.InternalTypeManager.<init>(InternalTypeManager.java:103)
        at oracle.mds.type.TypeManager.create(TypeManager.java:102)
        at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.<init>(MDSInstance.java:1795)
        at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.<init>(MDSInstance.java:1738)
        at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.findAndStoreMDSInstance(MDSInstance.java:2035)
        at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.getOrCreateInstance(MDSInstance.java:529)
        at oracle.mds.core.MDSInstance.getOrCreateInstance(MDSInstance.java:492)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFMDSConfig.getDefaultMDSInstance(ADFMDSConfig.java:450)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.FallbackConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(FallbackConfigImpl.java:64)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.FallbackConfigImpl.getDefaultMDSInstance(FallbackConfigImpl.java:95)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFConfigImpl.java:602)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFConfigImpl.java:582)
        at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFContextMDSConfigHelperImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFContextMDSConfigHelperImpl.java:274)
        at oracle.adf.share.ADFContext.getMDSInstanceAsObject(ADFContext.java:1757)
        at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext.initialize(ServletADFContext.java:494)
        at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext.initThreadContext(ServletADFContext.java:401)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.HttpBindingRequestHandler.initADFContext(HttpBindingRequestHandler.java:55)
        at oracle.adf.model.BindingRequestHandler.beginRequest(BindingRequestHandler.java:109)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:122)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
22/01/2012 2:59:05 AM oracle.jbo.uicli.mom.CpxUtils$Visitor logMainApplicationCpx
INFO: jndi:/localhost/KitUtility_sample/WEB-INF/classes/view/DataBindings.cpx
22/01/2012 2:59:06 AM oracle.jsp.logger.JspMessages infoCannotDispatchJspPage
INFO: Unable to dispatch JSP Page : Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/classloader/PolicyClassLoader
```

---

**Update**:

I have added all the custom libraries in `<tomcat>/lib` for deploying ADF as mentioned in the Oracle docs, url below                   [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28967/deployment_topics.htm#CIHJECBB) ,   The list of jars that i have included are                 '

```
adf-controller-api.jar
adf-controller-rt-common.jar
adf-controller-security.jar
adf-controller.jar
adf-richclient-api-11.jar
adf-richclient-impl-11.jar
adf-share-base.jar
adf-share-ca.jar
adf-share-security.jar
adf-share-support.jar
adflibfilter.jar
adflogginghandler.jar
adfm.jar
adfmweb.jar
adfsharembean.jar
adminclient.jar
annotations-api.jar
batik-anim.jar
batik-awt-util.jar
batik-bridge.jar
batik-codec.jar
batik-css.jar
batik-dom.jar
batik-ext.jar
batik-extension.jar
batik-gui-util.jar
batik-gvt.jar
batik-parser.jar
batik-script.jar
batik-svg-dom.jar
batik-svggen.jar
batik-swing.jar
batik-transcoder.jar
batik-util.jar
batik-xml.jar
cache.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha.jar
catalina-tribes.jar
catalina.jar
dms.jar
dvt-basemaps.jar
dvt-faces.jar
dvt-jclient.jar
dvt-trinidad.jar
dvt-utils.jar
ecj-3.7.jar
el-api.jar
glassfish.jstl_1.2.0.1.jar
identitystore.jar
inspect4.jar
jasper-el.jar
jasper.jar
javatools-nodeps.jar
javax.activation_1.1.0.0_1-1.jar
jewt4.jar
jrf-api.jar
jsf-api.jar
jsf-impl.jar
jsp-api.jar
mdsrt.jar
oc4j-internal.jar
ojdl.jar
ojsp.jar
poi-3.7-20101029.jar
prefuse.jar
servlet-api.jar
share.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-util.jar
trinidad-api.jar
trinidad-impl.jar
xml-apis-ext.jar
xmlef.jar
xmlparserv2.jar
```

---

**Update 2**:

I have found the Pcl.jar , but now when I try to access my page it tells me the following error

```
22/01/2012 11:36:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
22/01/2012 11:36:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
22/01/2012 11:36:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration', 'com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration@e99d0f')
22/01/2012 11:36:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration', 'com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration@e99d0f')
22/01/2012 11:37:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
oracle.jbo.NoDefException: JBO-25002: Definition null.cpx of type Application Definition not found
    at oracle.jbo.mom.DefinitionManager.findDefinitionObject(DefinitionManager.java:381)
    at oracle.jbo.mom.DefinitionManager.findDefinitionObject(DefinitionManager.java:296)
    at oracle.jbo.mom.DefinitionManager.findDefinitionObject(DefinitionManager.java:277)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.mom.JUApplicationDefImpl.findDefObject(JUApplicationDefImpl.java:83)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.mom.JUMetaObjectManager.loadCpx(JUMetaObjectManager.java:559)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.initializeBindingContext(ADFBindingFilter.java:348)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:122)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)'
```

Comment: Is this a modified Tomcat instance or something? Tomcat doesn't ship with `adfm.jar` by default. At least, the classpath is definitely a mess. In order to help you out of this, please list all JARs which you have in `/WEB-INF/lib` and mention in detail what exactly you changed to Tomcat's own libraries.

Comment: I have added all the custom libraries in <tomcat>/lib for deploying ADF as mentioned in the Oracle docs, url below

Comment: You are aware of that the doc you link to is for JDev 10g and not 11g. Then if you follow the doc your libs should end up under TOMCAT_HOME/common/lib, this however was for tomcat 5.x and not tomcat 6.

Comment: You can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628887/trying-to-deploy-oracle-adf-application-to-tomcat-7 Most errors result from wrong library management...