# Deploy ADF Application in Tomcat server

Tags: jsf, tomcat6, oracle-adf

I followed http://rohitatjade.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-deploy-adf-application-on-tomcat.html link to deploy adf application in tomcat. After complete all the step i hit my login URL but application throws below exception in browser. Kindly help me on this

**Exception**

*javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
    oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
root cause*

*java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError*
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManagerFactory._getDefaultListeners(RichWindowManagerFactory.java:111)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManagerFactory.access$100(RichWindowManagerFactory.java:31)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManagerFactory$ApplicationWindowListeners._getAppListeners(RichWindowManagerFactory.java:253)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManagerFactory$ApplicationWindowListeners.processWindowLifecylce(RichWindowManagerFactory.java:244)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManager._fireWindowLifecycleEvent(RichWindowManager.java:531)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManager._handleWindowOpened(RichWindowManager.java:574)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManager.renderLoopbackPage(RichWindowManager.java:1062)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:113)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.AdfFacesContextImpl
    java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Unknown Source)
    oracle.adf.view.rich.context.AdfFacesContext.(AdfFacesContext.java:592)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManagerFactory._getDefaultListeners(RichWindowManagerFactory.java:111)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManagerFactory.access$100(RichWindowManagerFactory.java:31)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManagerFactory$ApplicationWindowListeners._getAppListeners(RichWindowManagerFactory.java:253)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManagerFactory$ApplicationWindowListeners.processWindowLifecylce(RichWindowManagerFactory.java:244)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManager._fireWindowLifecycleEvent(RichWindowManager.java:531)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManager._handleWindowOpened(RichWindowManager.java:574)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RichWindowManager.renderLoopbackPage(RichWindowManager.java:1062)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:113)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to deploy Oracle-ADF application to Tomcat 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628887/trying-to-deploy-oracle-adf-application-to-tomcat-7)

Comment: These Classcast-Errors usually result from wrong Library Management in Tomcat. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628887/trying-to-deploy-oracle-adf-application-to-tomcat-7

Answer (score 0):

I guess your application makes use of ADF Security? Is so, ADF Essentials doesn't include ADF security so you will need to implement that yourself.
See the ADF Essentials FAQ: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/adfessentialsfaq-1837249.pdf

> What is included in Oracle ADF
>   Essentials
>   ?
>
> Oracle ADF
>   Essentials
>   includes the following Oracle ADF
>   components: Oracle ADF Faces
>   Rich Client Components
>   ,
>   Oracle ADF Controller, Oracle ADF Model and Oracle ADF
>   Business Components
>   .
>
> The following functionality is not included in
>   Oracle ADF
>   Essentials
>   , and requires the
>   full
>   Oracle ADF version
>   –
>   Oracle
>   ADF Mobile, Oracle ADF Desktop Integration,
>   Oracle ADF
>   Security,
>   The Oracle ADF
>   Web service data control, Oracle
>   ADF remote taskflows, Oracle ADF Business Component’s
>   Service Interfaces, Oracle AD
>   F Data C
>   ontrols for BI, Essbase
>   and BAM
>   , Integration with Oracle Fusion Middleware features
>   such as
>   MDS,
>   OPSS, OWSM, Enterprise Manager and
>   MBeans, High Availability and Clustering.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I am not using ADF security in my application.

Answer (score -1):

Did you deploy the ADF Essentials libraries into tomcat?
See the posts here: https://pinboard.in/search/u:OracleADF?query=tomcat