# Oracle ADF jDeveloper 12c - Application server compatibility

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, weblogic-10.x

We have developed a Oracle ADF web application using Jdeveloper11.1.2.3 and successfully deployed on Tomcat 6.x . We need to upgrade our applications. We need to use jDeveloper12c and Oracle Alta UI features in our app. So, If we use these features which are the application servers we will be able to deploy our web application. Is it possible to deploy Web application developed using jDev12c on Tomcat 7.x or higher ? If the answer is yes. Please guide us how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you used ADF Essentials to deploy on Tomcat, then the ADF Essential for 12c includes Alta and should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

> So, If we use these features which are the application servers we will
>   be able to deploy our web application.

Every application server (Glassfish, JBoss/Wildfly, WebLogic) should be able to handle that.

> Is it possible to deploy Web application developed using jDev12c on
>   Tomcat 7.x or higher ?

It looks like it is possible, but it may not be officially supported. See the [oracle support matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/index-091111.html).

> If the answer is yes. Please guide us how to achieve this.

[This blog post](http://rohitatjade.blogspot.de/2014/02/how-to-deploy-adf-application-on-tomcat.html) describes how to deploy an ADF application to Tomcat 7. In general it is similar to the setup for Tomcat 6.x, you need to put all the required ADF libs into `%TOMCAT_HOME%\lib`.

**See also:**

- [Trying to deploy Oracle-ADF application to Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628887/trying-to-deploy-oracle-adf-application-to-tomcat-7)
- [Oracle Fusion Middleware Docs - Deploying an ADF Java EE Application](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e16272/deploy_java_ee_app.htm)
- [Developing Your First Oracle Alta UI page with Oracle ADF Faces](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/a_guide_to_developing_your)